# Rotating color table object (for easy and consistent labeling)

Tags: javascript

I wanted to be able to consistently label an arbitrary number of objects on my site. It's pretty simple, but I if there's a more clever way...

```
// Usage:
// ColorTable.getColor('my link name');
ColorTable = {
  '_colors' : [
    '#F4BB2E',
    '#2DE656',
    '#66CCFF',
    '#6666FF',
    '#CC66FF',
    '#FF6FCF',
    '#FC4048'
   ],
  'tableSize' : function() { return this['_colors'].length; },
  'nextIndex' : function() {
    if (localStorage["ColorTable:_index"]===undefined) {
        localStorage["ColorTable:_index"] = -1;
    }
    rv = (parseInt(localStorage["ColorTable:_index"]) + 1) % this.tableSize();
    localStorage["ColorTable:_index"] = rv;
    return rv;
  },
  'getIndex' : function(key) {
    if (!localStorage["ColorTable:" + key]) {
      localStorage["ColorTable:" + key] = this.nextIndex();
    }
    return localStorage["ColorTable:" + key];
  },
  'setIndex' : function(key, index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < this.tableLength()) {
      localStorage["ColorTable:" + key] = index;
      return localStorage["ColorTable:" + key];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  'getColor' : function(key) {
    return this['_colors'][this.getIndex(key)];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor nitpicks:

None of you keywords are reserved words (especially if it starts with an underscore!) so encasing them in single-quotes is superfluous.

`ColorTable.tableSize` is an example of the [smurf-naming convention](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) (see item 21). Drop the second instance of table to become `ColorTable.size`

For `setIndex` you return two different datatypes: `index` on success, and `false` for failure. Since `index` is an arguements known to external code, what purpose does this serve? For consistency, you should return `true/false` for pass/fail **if you have to.** If you **have** to, how about a single point-of-return? You'd have to introduce a variable, and two more LOCs, but... `single point-of-return`!

But why not throw an exception? The existing mixed-type return suggests that calling code doesn't use the return value in any meaningful way.